# Creating compute instance from instance configuration

Tags: oci-python-sdk

I want to create a compute instance using oci-python-sdk in the same way as I would by clicking 'launch instance' in the "compute >> instance configurations >> instance configuration details" on the Oracle website.

I only found references to creating instances from custom images, but nothing on doing it from an existing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch an instance configuration with [launch_instance_configuration](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/client/oci.core.ComputeManagementClient.html?highlight=launch_instance_configuration#oci.core.ComputeManagementClient.launch_instance_configuration).

This example for launching an instance might help with a few more operations around the same: https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/launch_instance_example.py